# Custom Authorization Filter in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've a telerik mvc menu that binds to a sitemap. All links are properly setup and it binds successfully. But in the post methods, if model is posted back to the view for invalid models using `View(model)`, it breaks with below error. It works fine with PRG pattern i.e., if I redirect to view.

> INFO[System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. at
>   Telerik.Web.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.ControllerAuthorization.IsAccessibleToUser(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName, String actionName,
>   RouteValueDictionary routeValues) in f:\109\Griffin\Trunk
>   Full\Sources\Source\Telerik.Web.Mvc\Infrastructure\Implementation\ControllerAuthorization.cs:line
>   75 at
>   Telerik.Web.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.NavigationItemAuthorization.IsAccessibleToUser(RequestContext
>   requestContext, INavigatable navigationItem) in f:\109\Griffin\Trunk
>   Full\Sources\Source\Telerik.Web.Mvc\Infrastructure\Implementation\NavigationItemAuthorization.cs:line
>   38

By debugging through the code, I found it internally calls System.Web.MVC classes to retrieve authorization information for the node. Below is the line that returns null for invalid models otherwise it works fine if its a redirect or normal GET operation.

```
ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor = controllerDescriptor.FindAction(controllerContext, actionName);
if (actionDescriptor == null) 
{
     return null; **//it returns null for View(model)**
}
return new AuthorizationContext(controllerContext, actionDescriptor) { Controller = { ControllerContext = controllerContext } };
```

**FindAction method in System.Web.Mvc**. `RunSelectionFilters` is getting called from this method which is producing different outputs for normal and exception cases.

```
 public MethodInfo FindActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName)
        {
            List<MethodInfo> matchingAliasedMethods = this.GetMatchingAliasedMethods(controllerContext, actionName);
            matchingAliasedMethods.AddRange(this.NonAliasedMethods[actionName]);
            List<MethodInfo> ambiguousMethods = RunSelectionFilters(controllerContext, matchingAliasedMethods);
            switch (ambiguousMethods.Count)
            {
                case 0:
                    return null;

                case 1:
                    return ambiguousMethods[0];
            }
            throw this.CreateAmbiguousMatchException(ambiguousMethods, actionName);
        }
```

RunSelectionFilters method is returning `list2` for normal operations and `list` for exception cases.

```
private static List<MethodInfo> RunSelectionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, List<MethodInfo> methodInfos)
        {
            List<MethodInfo> list = new List<MethodInfo>();
            List<MethodInfo> list2 = new List<MethodInfo>();
            using (List<MethodInfo>.Enumerator enumerator = methodInfos.GetEnumerator())
            {
                Func<ActionMethodSelectorAttribute, bool> predicate = null;
                MethodInfo methodInfo;
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    methodInfo = enumerator.Current;
                    ICollection<ActionMethodSelectorAttribute> actionMethodSelectorAttributes = ReflectedAttributeCache.GetActionMethodSelectorAttributes(methodInfo);
                    if (actionMethodSelectorAttributes.Count == 0)
                    {
                        list2.Add(methodInfo);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (predicate == null)
                        {
                            predicate = attr => attr.IsValidForRequest(controllerContext, methodInfo);
                        }
                        if (actionMethodSelectorAttributes.All<ActionMethodSelectorAttribute>(predicate))
                        {
                            list.Add(methodInfo);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (list.Count <= 0)
            {
                return list2;
            }
            return list;
        }
```

And below is the custom authorization attribute. This attribute is applied to BaseController.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class AppActionAuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {       

        protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
           return DBService.IsAuthorized(httpContext.RequestContext().RouteData.Values);
        }

        public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }
            if (OutputCacheAttribute.IsChildActionCacheActive(filterContext))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("AuthorizeAttribute cannot be used within a child action caching block.");
            }

            if (this.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
            {
                HttpCachePolicyBase cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
                cache.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0L));
                cache.AddValidationCallback(new HttpCacheValidateHandler(this.CacheValidateHandler), null);
            }
            else
            {
                this.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }

        private void CacheValidateHandler(HttpContext context, object data, ref HttpValidationStatus validationStatus)
        {
            validationStatus = this.OnCacheAuthorization(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
        }

        protected virtual HttpValidationStatus OnCacheAuthorization(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
            }

            if (!this.AuthorizeCore(httpContext))
            {
                return HttpValidationStatus.IgnoreThisRequest;
            }
            return HttpValidationStatus.Valid;
        }
    }
```